# Uncaught Error: Could not find module `-private/system/references/record` imported from `ember-data/-private/system/references`

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

When I upload my demo project, built with the following command:

```
 ember build --environment=production
```

with data coming from ember-cli-mirage (configured to work also in production, with the method mentioned here: http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/server-configuration/#environment-options

I get this error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `-private/system/references/record` imported from `ember-data/-private/system/references`
```

I'm not sure which files would be relevant here I tried investigating in my project and:

```
% find . | grep system/references/record
./node_modules/ember-data/addon/-private/system/references/record.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-BSCsYUKC.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/record.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-TZ0VkmRd.tmp/ember-data/-private/system/references/record.js
./tmp/funnel-output_path-7Xt0eJcI.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/record.js

% find . | grep private/system/references
./node_modules/ember-data/addon/-private/system/references
./node_modules/ember-data/addon/-private/system/references/belongs-to.js
./node_modules/ember-data/addon/-private/system/references/has-many.js
./node_modules/ember-data/addon/-private/system/references/record.js
./node_modules/ember-data/addon/-private/system/references/reference.js
./node_modules/ember-data/addon/-private/system/references.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-BSCsYUKC.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references
./tmp/babel-output_path-BSCsYUKC.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/belongs-to.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-BSCsYUKC.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/has-many.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-BSCsYUKC.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/record.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-BSCsYUKC.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/reference.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-BSCsYUKC.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-TZ0VkmRd.tmp/ember-data/-private/system/references
./tmp/babel-output_path-TZ0VkmRd.tmp/ember-data/-private/system/references/belongs-to.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-TZ0VkmRd.tmp/ember-data/-private/system/references/has-many.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-TZ0VkmRd.tmp/ember-data/-private/system/references/record.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-TZ0VkmRd.tmp/ember-data/-private/system/references/reference.js
./tmp/babel-output_path-TZ0VkmRd.tmp/ember-data/-private/system/references.js
./tmp/funnel-output_path-7Xt0eJcI.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references
./tmp/funnel-output_path-7Xt0eJcI.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/belongs-to.js
./tmp/funnel-output_path-7Xt0eJcI.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/has-many.js
./tmp/funnel-output_path-7Xt0eJcI.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/record.js
./tmp/funnel-output_path-7Xt0eJcI.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references/reference.js
./tmp/funnel-output_path-7Xt0eJcI.tmp/modules/ember-data/-private/system/references.js
```

I saw around that many people recently complained about a similar problem with missing modules, but the problem seemed to be with windows forward slashes, and I don't think I have the same problem here, that problem is actually supposed to be resolved in the versions I'm using.

```
Ember      : 2.4.3
Ember Data : 2.4.1+4260f5771d
jQuery     : 2.2.2
```

here's the complete error:

```
    vendor-c7862e3….js:1 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `-private/system/references/record` imported from `ember-data/-private/system/references`n 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1i 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.reify 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.build 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1i 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.reify 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.build 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1i 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.reify 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.build 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1i 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.reify 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.build 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1i 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.reify 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.build 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1i 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.reify 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.build 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1i 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1requireModule 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1(anonymous function) 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:42e.default 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:42(anonymous function) 
@ myproject-ebb90ed….js:1a.exports 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1a.build 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1i 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1requireModule 
@ vendor-c7862e3….js:1(anonymous function) 
@ myproject-ebb90ed….js:4
```

Note that the project works fine on my local `ember server`, I get to the problem when I deploy it to the server

Answer (score 1):

resetting the modules worked, this is what I did:

```
rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp
npm cache clean
bower cache clean
npm install
bower install
```

Thanks,